# How can I edit the legend for the plot generated by this code?

Tags: r, plot, apriori

```
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
library(RColorBrewer)

trans = read.transactions("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tempAcccc/temRepo/main/TempFile.csv",format="basket", sep = ",",cols = c(1))
rule1 <- apriori(trans, parameter = list(support = 0.004,conf=0.05,target="rules"))
plot(rule1, measure=c("support", "confidence"),shading="order",col = brewer.pal(4,"Spectral"),main="Rules with Min_sup=0.004 and Min_conf=0.05")
```

This code generates [image: this graph].
I want to change the part where it says order to "iterations" how can I do this?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I have added the dataframe so that you can reproduce the results.

Comment: You should name required packages if you work with functions outside base R. Also, for me `read.transactions()` did not work with reading the DF from the environment. I had to read the file from source directly. I edited both in your post.

Although the documentation of `arulesViz` says `In addition to using order for shading, we also give the plot a different title (main). Othercontrol options includingpch(best with filled symbols: 20–25),cex,xlimandylimareavailable and work in the usual way expected by R-users.` it seems to me like a change of legend labels is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The legend in the default plot is fixed and cannot be changed. You can use ggplot2 as the engine (requires the latest version of `arulesViz`). This way you can use all ggplot functions to overwrite parts of the plot. Here is an example

```
library(ggplot2)
plot(rule1, measure=c("support", "confidence"), shading="order", engine = "ggplot") + 
   ggtitle("Rules with Min_sup=0.004 and Min_conf=0.05") + 
   labs(color = "Rule length") + 
   scale_color_discrete(type = brewer.pal(4,"Spectral"))
```